# Spring annotation relation with <form:form commandName="xy"

Tags: spring-mvc

I am new to Spring annotation and MVC. My first page is the home.jsp and now it does not comeup in the Tomcat server I get the error shown at the end in the console.
I tried to create a very simple annotation application. Here is the controller.

```
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller

    //@RequestMapping()
    public class UserLoginController {

    public UserLoginController(){

    }
        //@RequestMapping(value="/get" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    //@ModelAttribute("user")
        public String get(final ModelMap model) {

            User userForm = new User();
      model.addAttribute("userLogin", userForm);
       return "form";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value="/home.jsp", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String post(Model model) {

           String test=" inside here";

            return "success";
        }
    }
```

This is the JSP

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/header.jsp" %>

 <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
<title>iBank - Home-version 2.0</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center">Welcome to iBank-Dhiren</h1>
<h2 align="center">Your Online Bank Portal</h2>
<p align="center">   
Today is ${today}.<br/>
<a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/admin.htm">Modified Administration Site-version-1.0 </a>
</p>
</body>
</html>

<p>
    <form:form  method="post" commandName="user">
        <div>
            <form:label path="name">Name:</form:label>
            <form:input path="name"/>
            <form:errors path="name" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <form:label path="email">Email:</form:label>
            <form:input path="email" />
            <form:errors path="email" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="  OK  "/>
        </div>
    </form:form>
</p>

</html>
```

How does the JSP on submit now that it is supposed to go the the UserLoginController. I am not able to see any connections between annotation values and also my Tomcat server is coming back with this error.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:174)
```

Thanks
Dhiren

---

Ok I am not able to get any further . I tried all and still completely stuck.

My JSP 
home.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/header.jsp" %>

 <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
<title>iBank - Home-version 2.0</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center">Welcome to iBank-Dhiren</h1>
<h2 align="center">Your Online Bank Portal</h2>
<p align="center">   
Today is ${today}.<br/>
<a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/admin.htm">Modified Administration Site-version-1.0 </a>
</p>
</body>
</html>

<p>
    <form:form  method="post" action="/user.jsp" modelAttribute="user">

        <div>
            <form:label path="firstName">Name:</form:label>
            <form:input path="firstName"/>
            <form:errors path="firstName" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <form:label path="password">Password:</form:label>
            <form:input path="password" />
            <form:errors path="password" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <form:label path="middleName">Middle name:</form:label>
            <form:input path="middleName" />
            <form:errors path="middleName" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <form:label path="lastName">LastName:</form:label>
            <form:input path="lastName" />
            <form:errors path="lastName" />
        </div>


        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="  OK  "/>
        </div>
    </form:form>
</p>

</html>
```

My UserLoginController

```
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller

    //@RequestMapping()
    public class UserLoginController {

    public UserLoginController(){

    }
        //@RequestMapping(value="/get" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    //@ModelAttribute("user")
        public String get(final ModelMap model) {

            User userForm = new User();
      model.addAttribute("userLogin", userForm);
       return "form";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value="/user.jsp", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String post(final User user, final BindingResult result, Model mv) {

           String test=" inside here";

            return "success";
        }
    }
```

The User class

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

public class User {
/*  @NotEmpty
    @Size(max = 20)
    */
private String userId;
    /*@NotEmpty
    @Size(max = 20)
*/
private String password;
private String firstName;
private String middleName;
private String lastName;
//private int userAccessLevel;
/**
 * @return the userId
 */
public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}
/**
 * @param userId the userId to set
 */
public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}
/**
 * @return the password
 */
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
/**
 * @param password the password to set
 */
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
/**
 * @return the firstName
 */
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
/**
 * @param firstName the firstName to set
 */
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
/**
 * @return the middleName
 */
public String getMiddleName() {
    return middleName;
}
/**
 * @param middleName the middleName to set
 */
public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
    this.middleName = middleName;
}
/**
 * @return the lastName
 */
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
/**
 * @param lastName the lastName to set
 */
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
/**
 * @return the userAccessLevel
 *
public int getUserAccessLevel() {
    return userAccessLevel;
}
*/
/**
 * @param userAccessLevel the userAccessLevel to set
 *
public void setUserAccessLevel(int userAccessLevel) {
    this.userAccessLevel = userAccessLevel;
}*/

}
```

and these are the context.xml files 
servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

        <!-- Imports user-defined @Controller beans that process client requests -->

    <context:component-scan base-package="mytest.apps" />

</beans:beans>
```

Can some one tell me why the home.jsp does not come up

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>appServlet</display-name>
    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>  
  <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>  
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.xml</param-value>  
</context-param>  
<listener>  
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>  
</listener> 

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>

    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

With all these the error when I try to get to the first page of web application I get this error in Tomcat.

```
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned where no TLDs were found. Skipping JAR scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
log4j:ERROR Attempted to append to closed appender named [console].
Sep 14, 2011 10:02:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:194)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:119)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:89)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
.
.
Sep 14, 2011 10:02:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/AdministrativeApplication] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/home.jsp at line 25

22:     <form:form  method="post" action="/user.jsp" modelAttribute="user">
23:      
24:         <div>
25:             <form:label path="firstName">Name:</form:label>
26:             <form:input path="firstName"/>
27:             <form:errors path="firstName" />
28:         </div>


Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
```

Please help

Thanks
Dhiren

Comment: It's generally seen as bad practice to use scriptlet tags <% %> in jsp's. They are meant to contain view logic only, and its very easy to abuse their functionality. I would suggest avoiding them completely and instead setting values as request attributes and using ${} tags to display them instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
class User() {
    String name;
    String email;

    //bean getters and setters
}

public String post(Model model, User user) {
   ....
}
```

I just started using spring bindings a few days ago.

The way you have it set up I believe your form will try to create a "User" object with the properties "email" and "name".

*edit*

I think I understand the issue...

```
<form:form  method="post" commandName="user">
```

This is telling spring that you want to pre-populate the form with data from a user object. If this is what you want to do, then you need to provide the jsp with a request attribute called "user".

If you are trying to use the form to submit the data, which I believe is the case, I think you want to use this instead

```
<form:form  method="post" modelAttribute="user">
```

Comment: So would that not let me even show the first page which has this form to get displayed  ? Thanks

Comment: Ohh, are you trying to pre-populate the form with data, or user the form to submit the data?

Comment: no I am not repopulate at least that is not the intent just yet for the beginning. I want just an empty login sort of loginId input page show up with a submit. I am not able to get to display that page.

Comment: Did you see the edits I made to my answer?

Comment: Yes I saw your edits. thanks for the comments. I have a question. How does spring know which controller needs to be invoked when I do a post. How is spring able to tie UserLoginController to be invoked when I do the post . What exactly should my RequestMapping be like . Thanks

Comment: Generally, you specify an action on the form <form action="/submitMyForm"> and then your request mapping would be @RequestMapping({"/submitMyForm"}). When you submit the form it does a POST to the /submitMyForm url, which spring will use to direct the request to the controller.

Comment: My spring calls are still not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
model.addAttribute("**userLogin**", userForm); // in controller
return "form"; //in controller
```

in JSP you should give

```
form:form  method="post" action="/user.jsp" modelAttribute="userLogin"
```

(instead of `modelAttribute/commandName="user"`)

Try this u wont get

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute" expection.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simple............

```
model.addAttribute("**user**",userForm );
```

This means that, your command name should be exactly the same as the modelAttribute name...
so if your commandname in your jsp file is "user" then you model should add the attribute with the name "user".

Answer (score 0):

Your `post()` method should take command object as one of its argument:

```
public String post(final User user, final BindingResult result) {
```

In this case after posting data, fields `name` and `email` from form will be binded to `user.name` and `user.email` respectively.

Comment: I am not able to even get the first part, the form to display at all. Would this be causing the issue ?

Comment: What am I doing wrong still . Here is my modified code.

Comment: @djoshi why you commented out `@RequestMapping` of `get()` method? To what`url-pattern` you bind your `DispatcherServlet`? Lets start from begin: you should open page `/get` and see the form. After submit you should be at `/home.jsp` page. Where and what errors you are encounter?

Comment: I am not able to get to the home.jsp which is my start page. The get is commented becuase I use this method to call the action which is also not working. @RequestMapping(value="/home.jsp", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String post(Model model) {

           String test=" inside here";

            return "success";
        }

Comment: @djoshi You cannot get `/home.jsp` because you request it by `GET` method, but define only handler for `POST` method. I suggest uncomment `get()` method and call it instead for showing form.

Answer (score 0):

In your get method, adding the command object

```
public String get(final ModelMap model) {

  User userForm = new User();
  model.addAttribute("command", userForm);
  return "form";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"commandName" is used to bind model and data from form.
If you have class (MODEL) define like below:

```
public class UserQuery {

    public String message;

    public String getMessage()
    {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    } 
}
```

JSP file (DATA) :

```
<prefix:form method="POST" commandName="UserQuery">
  <sf:input path="message" /><br/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</prefix:form>
```

And GET/POST controller :

```
@Controller
public class ContactController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/Contact",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    ModelAndView Contact(Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("UserQuery",new Query());

        return new ModelAndView("contactView");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/Contact",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    ModelAndView Contact()
    {
        //Here you can get you're attribute and render it
        // in other view 
        return new ModelAndView("contactFormFiledView");
    }
}
```

GET method -> is used to create attribute "UserQuery" and bind it with model "Query" which is you're class.By bind I mean : if user click submit button in form , data from form are passed to attribute specified in "commandName".

Comment: I really think that 
 model.addAttribute("UserQuery", ...)  ,   commandName="UserQuery">  ,    and public class UserQuery    all have to match.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing your first issue.
Keep your home.jsp under resources folder inside the webapp section.
Make appropriate changes to the servlet-xml file as below.

`<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>resources/views/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
</bean>`

Add a method in your controller to handle requests for the home page.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public String displayLogin(Model model) { 
    model.addAttribute("login", new Login()); 
    System.out.println("Returning index page");
    return "index"; 
}
```

Your new url is going to be something like this http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/home

Make sure to add `model.addAttribute("login", new Login());` inside the displayLogin method mentioned above.

This should help.
Regards
BinoyC