# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/views/home.jsp (line: [25], column: [1]) Unable to find setter method for attribute: [commandName]

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have created a spring form and want to submit this from and display another jsp page. When i run this project i get the below exception. can anyone help me to understand why i am getting this error.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/views/home.jsp (line: [25], column: [1]) Unable to find setter method for attribute: [commandName]
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:292)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:115)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.evaluateAttribute(Generator.java:2998)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.generateSetters(Generator.java:3218)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.generateCustomStart(Generator.java:2404)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1894)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1544)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2389)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2441)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2447)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2389)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3657)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:256)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:384)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:345)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:603)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:170)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:312)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1325)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1069)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1008)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

JSP File :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <style>
.error {
    color: #ff0000;
}

.errorblock {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #ffEEEE;
    border: 3px solid #ff0000;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 16px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Spring's form textbox example</h2>

    <form:form method="POST" action="/customer" commandName="customer">
        <form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div" />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Username :</td>
                <td><form:input path="userName" />
                </td>
                <td><form:errors path="userName" cssClass="error" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>

</html>
```

When i use simple html form then it works properly but same thing if i am doing it through spring form it gives the error.

Controller Class :

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {


    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcomePage()
    {
        return "home";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/customer", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView submitForm(@RequestParam("userName") String name)
    {       
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("success");
        mv.addObject("userName", name);
        return mv;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your `/customer` code where the form needs to be submitted

Comment: I have added my controller class.  apart from it i have one Customer.java file with one property userName and their setter and getter method. - @KavishMittal

Comment: You are not taking `customer` as parameter in your controller:
`public ModelAndView submitForm(@RequestParam("userName") String name)` here. So its showing the error

Comment: I am new to spring, i don't understand how to do it, could you help to resolve this.if i use :
public ModelAndView submitForm(@ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer). This also does not work.

Answer (score 62):

Which version of Spring MVC are you using? I had the same problem, with maven dependency which is,

> group id  : org.springframework 
>   artifact id : spring-webmvc 
>   version     : 5.0.2.RELEASE

After version 5, commandName was removed, you should use modelAttribute, instead. 
I found it here, https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16037

I simply changed the commandName with modelAttribute.

```
<form:form modelAttribute="goal">
```

Comment: Had this error while going through "Introduction to Spring MVC" course on Pluralsight - the course uses Spring 3 and I'm using Spring 5. Changing 'commandName' to 'modelAttribute' solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Works fine !. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

1...OLD WAY = commandName

```
<form:form action="index" commandName="todo">
```

2...NEW WAY = modelAttribute

```
  <form:form action="index" modelAttribute="todo">
```

commandName was the old way of doing it and in new applications you should be using modelAttribute

Answer (score 1):

**`commandName` = name of a variable in the request scope or session scope that contaisn the information about this form, it should be a been.**

References: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/59966-exact-meaning-of-form-form-commandname

[Spring annotation relation with <form:form commandName="xy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356684/spring-annotation-relation-with-formform-commandname-xy)

In your `GET` method of `customer` which displays (returns) jsp file with the form, add model attribute like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/customer", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("customer",new Customer());

}
```

then try if it is displaying the form correctly.

Answer (score 0):

**Unable to find setter method for attribute: [commandName]t**

In this exception Spring Container want to know that, the name you used as "commandName" or "modelAttribute" in  jsp form tag, that attribute belong to which Domain(Class).? that means the `commandName="customer"` the customer  is instanceOf Customer model class .? or it is instanceof other..?  so that to ensure the Spring Container you have  to send Model to view in your HomeController of welcomePage() method just do that as follows.

```
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcomePage(Model model)
    {
        /* i am not sure what would be youe Model name for customer change that accord to your model name */
        Customer customerInstance = new Customer();
        model.addAttribute("customer", customerInstance);
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Уou can se there i added 2 parameter in Model attribute

1. Attribute Name i.e customer
2. Object name i.e customerInstance

The Model is an Interface which is a part of Spring API Library, **The Model interface**
Simply put, the model can supply attributes used for rendering views.
To provide a view with usable data, we simply add this data to its Model object. Additionally, maps with attributes can be merged with Model instances:
[If you want to know more go to this link](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-model-model-map-model-view)

Answer (score 0):

In your HomeController.java, you need to display form view with relevant model as following

```
@RequestMapping(value="/customer", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("customer",new Customer());
}
```

and if you are using spring-webmvc 5 or latest version then make sure to replace `commandName="customer"` with `modelAttribute="customer"`.
I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

This can be resolved by changing 'commandName' with 'modelAttribute' in the form.
With Spring 5 jars , commandName parameter is not working.

Please visit below link for more details on changes present in Spring framework 5:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x