# Spring MVC view problem from versions from 4 to 5

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, pom.xml

In **pom.xml** following dependencies.

```
<properties>
    <springframework.version>5.0.5.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <!--<springframework.version>4.3.20.RELEASE</springframework.version>-->
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet+JSP+JSTL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- jsr303 validation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

If I use 4.3.* version of **spring** everything OK. But if use the version **spring 5.*** the following error its occur.

```
Type Exception Report

Message org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.CustomerForm_jsp

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.CustomerForm_jsp
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:586)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:404)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:170)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:314)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1325)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1069)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1008)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Also firs lines in ***.jsp** files

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>

<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %> 
...
```

The full project you can find in https://github.com/ashot123/SpringMVCForm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46989072/org-apache-jasper-jasperexception-web-inf-views-home-jsp-line-25-column).

You use attribute `commandName`, and it is a reason why your jsp can not be compiled:

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="customer"
```

As written in a [ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16037) - with spring 5 you have to use `modelAttribute`.

Comment: Changing to modelAttribute helped. Thank you very much!